# ASP.Net 5 AuthorizationHandler Fail Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to add a custom authorization policy that can check a delimited list of groups supplied in a json config file. I am using ASP.Net 5 - MVC 6, along with windows authentication.

Everything is working fine, except for when I call Fail. Then nothing happens. A Blank screen is shown. Here is my HandleRequirementAsync method. I have tried various values for the task result. I have been googling like a madman, but with no luck. Hopefully someone can help.

**DESIRED RESULT:** I would like to redirect to a custom page on failure, but if that is not possible, at least be able to redirect back to the login page. The only thing that seems to have any effect is to throw an exception.

The pertinent registration code in Startup:

```
var appSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
services.Configure<Models.AppSettings>(appSettings);

services.AddMvc();

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RoleAuth", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new RolesRequirement(appSettings["AllowedGroups"])));
});

services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, RoleAuthorizationHandler>();
```

And the authorization classes:

```
public class RolesRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public RolesRequirement(string groups)
    {
        Groups = groups;
    }

    public string Groups { get; private set; }
}

public class RoleAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RolesRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RolesRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requirement.Groups))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(requirement.Groups);
            var groups = requirement.Groups.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            //we could check for group membership here.... maybe???
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                if (context.User.IsInRole(group))
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        context.Fail();
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also currently looking for a way to redirect when failure occurs, did you ever have any luck?

Comment: Nope Alex. No luck. Sorry.

Comment: An ugly workaround is to call the same code from `HandleRequirementAsync()` again in the `AccountController.AccessDenied()` method and redirect from there. In your case you need the required groups which makes this task difficult (reflection etc..). Adding stuff to the `HttpContext.Items` does not work, it gets cleared before reaching `AccessDenied()`... A last (even uglier) resort would be to have a static Dictionary<User,something> somewhere, add entries in `HandleRequirementAsync()` and remove them again in `AccessDenied()`. Yeah, If there was a better way I would also down-vote this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with what herostwist suggested, but Policies can challenge or forbid. After intesive research I came across what gives you direct access to the AuthorizationFilterContext like this (because they follow the naming convention and inherit from AuthorizeAttribute:

```
public class BudgetAccessFilterAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        //context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
        //TODO: determine if user has access to budget controllers, all of them could inherit from a Common Controller with this Filter
        if (false)
        {
            //if no access then
            context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Index", "Home", null);
        }
    }     
}
```

You can then decorate your controllers like this:

```
[BudgetAccessFilter]
public class BudgetItemController : Controller
{

}
```

And if you will have lots of controllers with the same checking, then they can all inherit from a base class with the annotation like this:

```
[BudgetAccessFilter]
public class BCommonController : Controller
{
}
```

And then clean controllers:

```
public class BudgetItemController : BCommonController
{
}
```

Comment: By going back to using attribute based authorisation, you are negating all the benefits of policy based authorisation. This filter wont play nice when you have multiple complex policies and roles. As authorisation requirements grow as your app grows, maybe some actions require policies like "Must be over 18" and some of those require additional policies like "Must have verified email" - you will quickly find that attribute based authorisation is holding you back.

Answer (score 3):

The only way i have found of doing this is, don't use context.Fail(), instead do this:

replace:

```
context.Fail();
```

with:

```
var mvcContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
mvcContext.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Action", "Controller", null);
context.Succeed(requirement);
```

allowing the context to succeed, will execute the context, which is now a redirect.

Comment: This is no longer an option since .net core 3 as far as I am aware. It works for sure in core 2.1 and 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

After trying Herotwists answer and seeing that it no longer works in .NET Core (`context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext` always returns `NULL`), I came up with this which seems to work fine in .NET 5.  It's a bit hacky though .... I'd really like to see how this **should** be done.  Surely it should be possible?

Anyway, here goes:

```
    if (accessAllowed)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
    else
    {
        var mvcContext = (context.Resource as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext);
        if (mvcContext != null)
        {
            mvcContext.Response.Redirect("/the-url-you-want-to-redirect-to");
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm using cookie authentication instead of windows but in my Configure method in the Startup.cs I have the following piece of code which tells it where to go

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    LoginPath = "/account/login",
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

Comment: This solution would only be relevant to cookie authentication.

Answer (score -4):

I don't know where you can configure the redirect result, but at least I was able to create such a "Account/AccessDenied.cshtml" file which will be shown in the fail case. "Account" is my class name and when fail happened, browser was redirected to this Url: (http://localhost:39339/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2Fapp%2Fequipments)

Here is my controller code (Web/AccountController.cs) as well.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult AccessDenied()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```